# Get Twitter Follower Count by User ID in 2023

Tags: twitter, twitter-api-v2

I'm wondering if it's possible with the current free-tier API to get twitter follower count from the twitter V2 API. I'm able to post tweets programmatically but am running into the following issue when I try to request user info with the same credentials:

```
{
    data: {
      client_id: '27401878',
      detail: 'When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer App that is attached to a Project. You can create a project via the developer portal.',
      registration_url: 'https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/projects/overview',
      title: 'Client Forbidden',
      required_enrollment: 'Appropriate Level of API Access',
      reason: 'client-not-enrolled',
      type: 'https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/client-forbidden'
    }
  }
```

It's unclear to me in the docs if this is now behind a paywall or a feature that requires more digging to implement. I'm wondering if anyone has solved this.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use

```
https://api.twitter.com/2/users/me
```

Otherwise you can try the v1.1 API where you can access public information from any account by passing the Bearer token from your Developer account. The response contains `followers.count` that you can use.

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=alfrednerstu
```